# Different colors for each circle - D3 circle pack

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, colors, circle-pack

I have done the bubble chart. But I'm not getting different colors for each bubble. How could I do that? How could I give different colors for each circle? And the circle data with the highest value should always come at the center surrounded by other bubbles.

Snippet:

```
var diameter = 200,
format = d3.format(",d"),
color = ["#7b6888", "#ccc", "#aaa", "#6b486b"];

 var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
.size([diameter, diameter]);

   var svg = d3.select("#bubbleCharts").append("svg")
.attr("width", diameter + 10)
.attr("height", diameter)
.attr("class", "bubble");

  var a;

   d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
   var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + 20 + "," + d.y + ")"; });

   node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r+ 7; })
  .style("fill", function(d) { 
  for(a in color){
  return color[a]; };} );

    node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".3em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.value+"%"; });
  });

   function classes(root) {
    var classes = [];

    function recurse(name, node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
      else classes.push({packageName: name, value: node.value});
   }

     recurse(null, root);
      return {children: classes};
     }
```

My data is:

```
   {
     "name": "Spending Activity",
     "children": [
         {"name": "Petrol", "value": 60},
         {"name": "Travel", "value": 10},
         {"name": "Medical", "value": 25},
         {"name": "Shopping", "value": 5}
     ]
   }
```

Comment: In the fill function try passing d & i and then returning color[i]. Oh, and you might have to use attr instead of style (I cash never remember).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a colour scale to get the fill colours:

```
var colour = d3.scale.category20();
```

Then you can set the fill colour like this:

```
 node.append("circle")
     .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r+ 7; })
     .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colour(i); });
```

As for the positions of the nodes, the pack layout doesn't provide any functionality to affect that, i.e. you cannot force a particular circle to be in the center.

Comment: How can we add a legend to this bubble chart?

Comment: This is an entirely different question. It depends on what kind of legend you want etc.

Comment: I'm displaying the values inside the circle. I need the names as the legend. For an instance, in the above provided data, if the value is 60, i need that name "Petrol" in the legend. Thanks

Comment: It might be better if you posted that as a separate question, along with the code that demonstrates what you have tried.

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot read property 'children' of undefined " error only in chrome.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff do you know how one would go about filling in colors for [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535) I want to fill in the white circles based on the value in the json file. I am trying to fill in colors for my [website](http://www.global-watch.info/overview). If you input "Cuba" , "Yearly", "2012" into the form you will get a zoomable circle. I need the white circles to change color depending on their value.

Comment: @CatherineAlv I would post a separate question about this.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I posted a separate question on Stack Overflow. Here is a link to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341177/zoomable-circle-packing-color-change

Answer (score 1):

This reference card may be handy while choosing built-in D3 color sets:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use colorbrewer color sets: (see example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5577023))

[image]