# Zoomable Circle Packing Color Change

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, circle-pack

I implemented my own version of https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535, but I would like to fill in the white circles with colors representing the data I am dealing with. For example some of the children in my json look like this:

[image]

I would like to fill in the white circles with the numerical numbers displayed. I have access to those numbers in my code. Is there a way for me to fill in the color for each circle that can also represent negative numbers? In order to see a working version of this check out my website [here](http://www.global-watch.info/overview) and enter the following information into the form "Cuba", "Yearly", and "2016."

Here is my code:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
     margin = 20,
     diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
     g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

  var format = d3.format(",d")

  var color = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-1, 5])
      .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
      .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

  var pack = d3.pack()
      .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
      .padding(2);


var poot = {"name":"flare","children":[]}
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
             var data = {};
             data.country = $("#country").val();
             data.timeframe = $("#timeframe").val();
             data.eventdate = $("#eventdate").val();
             $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "/overview",
                data: JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'),
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                success: function(result) {
                   //poot = add_simple(poot,result["result"])
                   draw(poot,result["result"]);
                  // poot = getData(poot,result["result"])
                }
              });
             })

function draw(root,updates_dict){

  function getData(json,dict_country){

   function find_index(curr_json,country){
      var country_children = curr_json["children"]
      for (var i=0; i < country_children.length;i++){
        if (country_children[i]["name"] == country){
          return i
        }
      }
      return -1
    }

    function event_children(event_dict){ //returns a list with event children
      var time_lst = []
      var event_names = Object.keys(event_dict)
      for (var i = 0; i<event_names.length; i++){
        var event_type = {}
        event_type["name"] = event_names[i]
        event_type["children"] = []
        event_info = event_dict[event_names[i]]
       // console.log(event_info)
        total_topic = event_info["ArticleMentions"]
        delete event_info["ArticleMentions"]
        for (var key in event_info){
          key_obj = {}
          key_obj["name"] = key + " => " + event_info[key]
          key_obj["size"] = total_topic / 2
          event_type["children"].push(key_obj)
        }
        time_lst.push(event_type)
      }
      return time_lst
    }

    function add_child(insertname,bool,tot){
      var new_add = {}
      new_add["children"] = []
      if (bool == true){
        new_add["name"] = insertname + " => " + tot
      }
      else{
        new_add["name"] = insertname
      }
      return new_add
    }

    var country = dict_country["Country"]
    var timeframe = dict_country["Timeframe"]
    var date = dict_country["Date"]
    var total = dict_country["Total"]
    var info = dict_country["Overview"]
    var country_ind = find_index(json,country) //returns index of country
    if (country_ind == -1){
      var country_dict = add_child(country) //here  {"name":Ecuador,"children":[]}
      var timeframe_dict = add_child(timeframe) //here {"name":"Daily","children":[]}
      var add_date = add_child(date,true,total) //here {"name":"20150709","children":[]}
      add_date["children"] = event_children(info)
      timeframe_dict["children"].push(add_date)
      country_dict["children"].push(timeframe_dict)
      json["children"].push(country_dict)
      return json
    }
    else{ //the country exists
        timeframe_ind = find_index(json["children"][country_ind],timeframe)
        if (timeframe_ind == -1){
          //create new timeframe and make the same additonas above
          var new_timeframe = add_child(timeframe) //{"name": Daily, "children":[]}
          var new_date = add_child(date,true,total) //{"name":date,children:[]}
          new_date["children"] = event_children(info)
          new_timeframe["children"].push(new_date)
          json["children"][country_ind]["children"].push(new_timeframe)
          return json
        }
        else{
          var event_day = add_child(date,true,total)
          event_day["children"] = event_children(info)
          json["children"][country_ind]["children"][timeframe_ind]["children"].push(event_day)
          return json
        }
    }


  }

  var root = getData(root,updates_dict)
  root = d3.hierarchy(root)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  var focus = root,
      nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
      view;

  var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes,function(d){
      return d.country; //I thinks this will fail
    })

  circle.exit().remove()

  circle = circle.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
        .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); })
        .merge(circle);


  var text = g.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes,function(d){
       return d.country;
    })

  text.exit().remove();

  text = text.enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .merge(text)

  text = text.style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");
  node.append("title")
    .text(function(d){
      return d.country})

  svg
      .style("background", color(-1))
      .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

  function zoom(d) {
    var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

    var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
        });

    transition.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
  }

  function zoomTo(v) {
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
  }

}
```